# OpenLayers 6.9: Cannot load Yandex Map

Tags: openlayers, yandex

I tried to load Yandex map using OpenLayers library 6.9 and it's not working. A part of code for that is:

```js
    var yandexLayer = new ol.layer.Group({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        url: 'http://vec0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
                        projection: 'EPSG:3395',
                        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                            extent: [-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244]
                        })
                    })
                })]
        });
```

When I try to change the URL to Satellite view (`https://sat01.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&v=3.379.0&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`) it's working. Does someone have any idea what is the problem or is there any other URL for the road view?

Comment: Those tiles appear to have been deprecated.  Checking the network activity of https://yandex.com/maps/ show it uses vector tiles with a base url of https://core-renderer-tiles.maps.yandex.net/vmap2/tiles  The tiles seem to use a propriety vector format which is not supported by OpenLayers.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. But do you have any idea how to make it works?

Comment: Image tiles are still used on https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsapi/  The minimum url needed (without language option, etc.) is `https://core-renderer-tiles.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much, Mike!